# Strange multiple log output within for loop in iOS and Core Data

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nslog

I use empty application template with Core Data checkbox being on in iOS 7 application and Xcode 5, and when I write the following code in order to do background fetch in Core Data:

```
-(void)populateDatabase {
    for (NSUInteger counter = 0; counter < 1000; counter++) {
        Person *person = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:NSStringFromClass([Person class]) inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
        person.firstName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"First name %lu", (unsigned long)counter];
        person.lastName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Last name %lu", (unsigned long)counter];
        person.age = @(counter);
    }
    NSError *error = nil;
    if ([self.managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"managed to populate the database");
    }else{
        NSLog(@"failed to populate the database, error at %@", error);
    }
}
```

```
    -(NSFetchRequest *)newFetchRequest {
        NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:NSStringFromClass([Person class])];
        request.fetchBatchSize = 20;
        request.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(age >= 100) AND (age
```

```
-(void)processPersons:(NSArray *)paramPersons {
    for (Person *person in paramPersons) {
        NSLog(@"First name = %@, last name = %@, age = %ld", person.firstName, person.lastName, (long)person.age.integerValue);
    }
}
```

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    [self populateDatabase];

    __weak NSManagedObjectContext *mainContext = self.managedObjectContext;
    __weak AppDelegate *weakSelf = self;
    __block NSMutableArray *mutablePersons = nil;

    NSManagedObjectContext *backgroundContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType];
    backgroundContext.persistentStoreCoordinator = self.persistentStoreCoordinator;

    [backgroundContext performBlock:^{
        NSError *error = nil;
        NSArray *personIDs = [backgroundContext executeFetchRequest:[weakSelf newFetchRequest] error:&error];
        if (personIDs != nil && error == nil) {
            mutablePersons = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:personIDs.count];
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                for (NSManagedObjectID *personId in personIDs) {
                    Person *person = (Person *)[mainContext objectWithID:personId];
                    [mutablePersons addObject:person];
                }
                [weakSelf processPersons:mutablePersons];
            });
        }else {
            NSLog(@"failed to execute the fetch request");
        }
    }];

    self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

and then execute it, the debugging screen outputs about three to five times for each iteration of the loop in `processPerson:` method. Why does such strange behavior occur despite me writing the debug function only one time per each iteration.

I created `Person` entity on which `firstName` and lastName's type are set at string and age at integer32.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you’re populating the database on each launch and saving it.

If you’re just debugging, comment out `[self populateDatabase];` after it runs once.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know how Core Data worked internally. Then when I ship the app, how should I implement the DB initialization? Run `[self populateDatabase];` only when an user launches the app for the first time? Or should I call it every time an user launches the app, and delete the whole DB when he terminates the app? Or is there any other conventions that most developers do instead?

Comment: Well, when you call `save:` and the context is configured with the persistent store coordinator, the changes are committed to the file. Next time you open the same file, you’ll have all the old data. Do you need one “read-only” database pre-shipped with the app? You can generate it beforehand and then just include it in the app bundle.

Comment: Yeah, I need read-functionality only and wouldn't use insert or delete (or update). So you mean, I can generate the entire DB and its managed objects before I ship it to the app store and hence don't need to bother writing populateDatabase or any such method, right?

Comment: That’s right. The important thing is to create this database with Core Data and not with some other tool.